# Ошибка компилятора

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Почему не компилируется нормально следующая программа?

```
uses LinkedList;
begin
  var L := new TLinkedList<integer>();
end.
```

, где LinkedList:

```
///Классы связных списков.
unit LinkedList;

type
  ///Узел односвязного списка.
  TListNode<TValue> = class
  private 
    _Value: TValue;
    _Next: TListNode<TValue>;
  public 
    ///Значение узла.
    property Value: TValue read _Value write _Value;
    ///Ссылка на следующий элемент.
    property Next: TListNode<TValue> read _Next write _Next;

    constructor(v: TValue);
    begin
      Value := v;
      Next := nil;
    end;

    ///Вернуть строковое представление объекта.
    function ToString(): string; override;
    begin
      Result := Format('{0}<{1}>: Value = {2}', GetType().Name, Value.GetType().Name, Value);
    end;

    ///Вывести на экран объект, преобразованный к строковому представлению.
    procedure Print() := Write(ToString());

    ///Вывести на экран объект, преобразованный к строковому представлению и перейти на новую строку.
    procedure Println() := Writeln(ToString());
  end;

  ///Класс узла двусвязного списка.
  TListNodeDC<TValue>=class(TListNode<TValue>)
  private 
    _Previous: TListNodeDC<TValue>;
  public 
    ///Ссылка на предыдущий элемент списка.
    property Previous: TListNodeDC<TValue> read _Previous write _Previous;

    constructor(v: TValue);
    begin
      inherited Create();
      Previous := nil;
    end;
  end;

///Создает новый узел односвязного списка.
function NewNode<TValue>(v: TValue) := new TListNode<TValue>(v);

///Создает новый узел односвязного списка.
function NewNode<TValue>(v: TValue; nxt: TListNode<TValue>): TListNode<TValue>;
begin
  Result := NewNode(v);
  Result.Next := nxt;
end;

///Создает новый узел двусвязного списка.
function NewNodeDC<TValue>(v: TValue) := new TListNodeDC<TValue>(v);

///Создает новый узел односвязного списка.
function NewNodeDC<TValue>(v: TValue; nxt, prev: TListNodeDC<TValue>): TListNodeDC<TValue>;
begin
  Result := NewNodeDC(v);
  Result.Next := nxt;
  Result.Previous := prev;
end;


type
  ///Класс односвязного списка.
  TLinkedList<TValue> = class
  private 
    _Head: TListNode<TValue>;
    _Count: integer;
  public 
    ///Головной узел списка.
    property Head: TListNode<TValue> read _Head;
    ///Количество элементов списка.
    property Count: integer read _Count;

    constructor();
    begin
      _Head := new TListNode<TValue>();
    end;

    ///Вернуть строковое представление объекта.
    function ToString(s: string): string;
    begin
      var n := Head;
      while n <> nil do
      begin
        if n.Next <> nil then
          Result += Format('[{0}]{1}', n.ToString(), s)
        else
          Result += Format('[{0}]', n.ToString());
        n := n.Next;
      end;
    end;

    ///Вывести на экран объект, преобразованный к строковому представлению.
    procedure Print() := Write(ToString(NewLine));

    ///Вывести на экран объект, преобразованный к строковому представлению и перейти на новую строку.
    procedure Println() := Writeln(ToString(NewLine));

    ///Процедура добавления в начало списка.
    procedure Add(var node: TListNode<TValue>);
    begin
      node.Next := Head;
      _Head := node;
      Inc(_Count);
    end;

    ///Процедура удаления из начала списка.
    procedure Remove();
    begin
      if Head <> nil then
      begin
        _Head := _Head.Next;
        Dec(_Count);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

При попытке компиляции программы вылетает:

```
Внутренняя ошибка компилятора в модуле [pabcnetc.exe] :'System.Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
   в PascalABCCompiler.NETGenerator.ILConverter.ConvertCommonGenericInstanceTypeMembers(ICommonGenericTypeInstance value)
   в PascalABCCompiler.NETGenerator.ILConverter.ConvertTypeInstancesMembersInFunction(ICommonFunctionNode func)
   в PascalABCCompiler.NETGenerator.ILConverter.ConvertFunctionHeaders(ICommonNamespaceFunctionNode[] funcs)
   в PascalABCCompiler.NETGenerator.ILConverter.ConvertFromTree(IProgramNode p, String TargetFileName, String SourceFileName, CompilerOptions options, String[] ResourceFiles)
   в PascalABCCompiler.Compiler.Compile()'
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код** для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Протестировал на версии  3.3.0.1590. Получил ошибку

```
Внутренняя ошибка компилятора в модуле [pabcnetc.exe] :'System.Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
```

Избежал появления ошибки так: Вначале открыл модуль LinkedList.pas, откомпилировал его, затем уже компилировал ваш код - всё прошло нормально. Поэтому обновитесь до последней версии и попробуйте так же.

Почему так - не отвечу, проект PASCALABC.NET ещё достаточно сыроват.

Comment: так-то ошибка в вопросе та же самая. Там просто еще StackTrace добавлен

Comment: @Grundy А я и не спорю :) Разве что выразился двусмысленно, - могу исправить. Факт в том, что ошибки удается избежать, предварительно откомпилировав модуль.

Comment: Когда с генериками работаешь в ABC, часто так бывает: если они в отдельном юните, его нужно обязательно скомпилировать ДО компиляции всей программы.

Comment: У меня стоит версия 3.3.1607. Модуль компилировал до компиляции программы.